# phpunit mock and php generators

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Class: https://github.com/Keanor/generatortest/blob/master/src/SomeClass.php

Test: https://github.com/Keanor/generatortest/blob/master/tests/SomeClassTest.php

Output:

```
keanor@keanor-pc ~/www/generatortest $ ./vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 5.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)class Generator#23 (0) {
}


Time: 31 ms, Memory: 3.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) AppTest\SomeClassTest::testMethod2
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:method1> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

if "yield" is replaced by "return" test succeeds!

Mock does not work with a generators?

Comment: until you don't iterate the result of the function, this is not really called

Comment: @Matteo thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use it like a generator:

```
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeClass::class)
        ->setMethods(['method1'])
        ->getMock();
    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('method1')
        ->willReturn('');
    foreach ($mock->method2() as $result) {
        var_dump($result);
    }
```

instead of:

```
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeClass::class)
        ->setMethods(['method1'])
        ->getMock();
    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('method1')
        ->willReturn('');
    $result = call_user_func([$mock, 'method2']);
    var_dump($result);
```